# Keycloak 15.0.2 Integration with IBM Websphere Portal server version 6.1 using JDK 6

Tags: keycloak, websphere-7, websphere-portal, ltpa

In **Current production** we are running Two Applications one on WebSphere Application Server 7.0 and one with WebSphere Portal Server 6.1. User currently login to WebSphere Portal and can redirect to WAS if needed. The SSO done by LTPA based SSO on both server. So no need to login to WAS if user already logged in WPS (Portal Server).

Now **our requirement** to allow Keycloak user to login to WebSphere Portal server. For this we have setup the Keycloak server and Keycloak is successfully redirecting the user to WebSphere Portal server. But we are stuck to validate the Keycloak openID token in WebSphere to retrieve the user and set UserPrinciple in WebSphere Portal server.

How we can create the PortalSession from Keycloak sso token?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal first with the authentication at the Websphere Application Level, check this link, although is related to HCL Connections, it is also using Wesbphere Application Server layer, so the steps there are the same one -> https://opensource.hcltechsw.com/connections-doc/v8-cr1/admin/secure/t_keycloak_oidc_websphere.html

By the way, you are dealing with a very OLD release of Websphere Portal, outdated, and out of support.  I really hope that at least you have a more modern Websphere Application Websphere at the back.